# How to check if value exists in firebase databse

Tags: java, android

I have this Database:

[image]

I want to find out if a Email (value in database) already exists. So I have to iterate through each child of "email" and check if the value equals to the String inputMail.

I tried the following Code, but It doesn´t work, can anybody help me please? Thank u

```
final String input_mail = et_email.getText().toString();

            DatabaseReference email = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("email");

            email.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String emailVal = ds.getValue(String.class);
                        if (emailVal.equals(input_mail)) {

                           //Toast exists
                        }


                        else {

                            //Toast not exists
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

In conclusion if I enter person1@m.de it should give out a toast that it exist

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very easy way . Make your email as child . You have to replace the dot from the email and set it as child. (you can't use the email directly to a child)

```
static String encodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(".", ",");
}

static String decodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(",", ".");
}
```

Then you can easily match it like this :

```
            final String input_mail = et_email.getText().toString();

            DatabaseReference email = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("email");

            email.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                      if(datasnapshot.child(input_mail).exits){
                          //Toast exists
                       }else {
                           //Toast not exists
                       }

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```